# What is an efficient/quick way to populate a C# struct with SQL table info?

Tags: c#, .net, sql

In a nutshell:  I have some database table data that I want to populate c# structs with.

For example:

```
struct Phone
{
    public int PhoneID;
    public string Number;
}
struct Patient
{
    public Phone WorkPhone;
}
```

And the SQL tables look like this:

```
Patient table:  
    Patient ID, Patient Name, etc.  
Phone table:  
    PhoneID, Number, Phone Type etc.
```

Basically the structs are mirrors of the SQL tables.

I have the primary key (`PhoneID`), that I am passing through a select statement.  So I will only retrieve one row in the case of the patient or up to 5 rows for the Phone table (They can have `Work`, `Cell`, `Home`, etc).

I don't have a great way to stuff this table into a struct easily.  What I am doing now is one by one.  You can see for hundreds of variables per patient, it's a very tedious and highly code intensive process.  Is there some way, maybe I can have a variable in the variable name, for example if the column name is Phone then it would stuff the Phone variable.  Hope that makes sense.

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Phone p WHERE p.StatusID = 'A' AND ObjectTypeID = 'PA' AND ObjectID = '" + PatientID.ToString() + "'";
SqlDataAdapter a1 = new SqlDataAdapter(query, dataConnection);
DataTable t1 = new DataTable();
a1.Fill(t1);
DataTableReader r1 = t.CreateDataReader();
//object value = null;
while (reader.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < r1.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        if (!r1.IsDBNull(i))
        {
            if reader.GetValue(i)
            switch (r1.GetName(i))
            {
                case "PhoneID": { pr.HomePhone.PhoneID = (int)reader.GetValue(i); break; }
                case "PhoneTypeID": { pr.HomePhone.PhoneTypeID = (string)reader.GetValue(i); break; }
                case "ObjectID": { pr.HomePhone.ObjectID = (int)reader.GetValue(i); break; }
                case "ObjectTypeID": { pr.HomePhone.ObjectTypeID = (string)reader.GetValue(i); break; }
```

Comment: why are you using structs? are you aware of their limitations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be that you need an ORM like [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx), [Lightspeed](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed) or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx).

If they'd be overkill, check out one of the new mini ORM-like libraries like [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive).

Comment: I'm taking a look at Lightspeed.  I had no idea ORMs even existed, I'll also look at the others.  Thanks to all for the great ideas!

Comment: Could be AutoMapper also used for this?

Answer (score 2):

A fullblown ORM is probably out of the question, but you could use reflection to map the values from your datatable to your objects. Alternatively, you could also resort to things like [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

Answer (score 2):

Dapper (stackoverflows lightweight object mapper) seems like a strong candidate. Used it in a few projects so far and love it. Simple, quick and painless.

Unless structs are a requirement, I would suggest switching to classes.

http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Comment: Why do you make that suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dictionary. The logic would be:

```
while (reader.Read())
            {
                Dispute disp = new Dispute();
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    if (!reader.IsDBNull(i))
                    {
                        //Getting a property name associated to filed name
                        string mappedProperty = dataMapping[reader.GetName(i)];
                        //Getting handle to the property
                        PropertyInfo fld = typeof(Dispute).GetProperty(mappedProperty);
                        //Setting property value to field value
                        fld.SetValue(disp, reader.GetValue(i));
                    }
                }
            }
```

All you need in this case would be a dictionary `dataMapping` that would associate your field names to properties in your object. This is how I do it. It can handle any field structure with little amendments to 
code - only dictionary needs to be amended.

The better way though would be to reverse it and use object structure as a driver.

1. Fill in the intermediary dictionary  with fieldName, filedValue
2. Pass it on to the a function with the object that needs to be filled in with the values
3. Cycle through all objects properties and assign values using reversed `dataMapping` dictionary.

In this case the routine basically becomes object-type-independent and only assigns values of found fields. It can also be abstracted to a base class as method and inherited to the actual class.

Answer (score 1):

Mutable structs in general is a pretty bad idea.

You should consider using one of many available ORM, which exist specifically for this purpose.

If you are bent on making something custom, then general idea is pretty simple.

1. Examine given type using reflection
2. Bind type field/properties to the data reader field names using either dynamic compilation or expressions
3. Magic happens

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer provided by @Bevan I would add to the list the Entity Framework 4.1 (EF 4.1 is vastly different than other versions), [My Generation](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx) with sample template like Gentle.NET, or Code Smith.